# Node.js ignoring code to read a file that does not yet exist

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to write some basic code for use in a larger chatbot later. The code takes a user input, checks to see if a file already exists and if it does not, pull data from an api and save the file.

I can get each part working independently (for example, noting out the readfile saves the file and noting out the write successfully reads the file) however when I try to run them together I get an ENOENT error. The entire code can be seen below.

```
const path = require('path');
const readline = require('readline-sync');
const fs = require('fs');
const request = require('request');

//put api url into variable
const api = "http://vocadb.net/api/";

var command = readline.question("enter a command: ");
//only run with commands that start with !
if (command.startsWith('!')) {
  if (command.startsWith('!artist')) {

    //split input, strip command char and use as file name
    userCommand = command.replace('!', '');
    userCommand = userCommand.split(' ');
    var filename = userCommand[0] + userCommand[1] + ".txt";
    var file = path.basename(filename);

    //if file does not exist, fetch JSON from api and save to file
    if (!fs.existsSync(file)) {
      console.log("true");
      request(api + "artists?query=" + userCommand[1] + "&artistType=producer&lang=English", function(error, response, body) {
        if(err) throw err;
        console.log(body);
        var artist = JSON.parse(body);
        console.log(artist);
        //if json has no items do not create file, print incorrect and stop execuution
        if (artist['items'] == '') {
          console.log("Artist could not be found");
          throw err;
        } else {
          fs.writeFile(file, JSON.stringify(artist), (err) => {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log('file saved');
          });
        }
      });
    }

    fs.readFile(file, 'utf8', (err, data) => {
      if (err) throw err;
      artist = JSON.parse(data);
      request(api + "songs?artistId=" + artist['items'][0]['id'] + "&maxResults=2&getTotalCount=false&sort=RatingScore&lang=English", function(error, response, body) {
        var songs = JSON.parse(body);
        console.log(artist['items'][0]['name'] + "\n" + artist['items'][0]['defaultName'] + "\n");
        console.log("Top songs:\n" + songs['items'][0]['name'] + "\n" + songs['items'][0]['defaultName'] + "\n" + songs['items'][0]['artistString'] + "\n");
        console.log(songs['items'][1]['name'] + "\n" + songs['items'][1]['defaultName'] + "\n" + songs['items'][1]['artistString']);
      });
    });
  }
}
```

It seems like node skips all the code just before the request since the console.log("true) does return but nothing afterwards

So far I have tried separating them into functions (which might be a better etiquette), changing the readFile to readFileSync, using request.get(...).on(...)

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Changing `async` to `Sync` methods is totally wrong..  In this particular case you just need to move your read into your write callback, as that's when your wanting it to run.  But doing this you will soon find you get into what's called callback hell..  This is were promises come to the rescue, and even better `async / await`..  So as a suggestion, do some research on Promises & async / await, it will be time well spent.

Comment: `fs.readFile()` runs together (asynchronously) with your `request()` and therefore cannot read your file as `request()` does not finish before `fs.readFile()`. As suggested, try reading about `Promises` and/or `async await` if you're on Node 8+. Or what you can try doing is to move `fs.readFile()` into `request()`'s callback.

Answer (score 0):

Your code just need a few minnor corrections. Since I don't have access to your API, I'm using a public one (last.fm/api) but it works with JSON almost the same way you want.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var request = require('request');
var api = 'http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?callback=&method=';

var file = "test.txt";
var userCommand = 'amy';

if (!fs.existsSync(file)) {
    console.log("file not found");
    request(api + "artist.getinfo&artist=" + userCommand + '&api_key=57ee3318536b23ee81d6b27e36997cde&format=json&_=1520772613660', function(err, response, body) {
        if (err) throw err;
        else {
            var data = JSON.parse(body);
            if (!data.artist) {
                console.error("Artist could not be found");
                throw err;
            } else {
                fs.writeFile(file, JSON.stringify(data), function (err) {
                    if (err) throw err;
                    else console.log('file saved');
                });
            }
        }
    });
} else {
    console.log('found file "' + file + '"');
    fs.readFile(file, 'utf8', function (err,data) {
        if (err) throw err;
        else {
            artist = JSON.parse(data);
            request(api + "artist.getTopTracks&artist=" + userCommand + "&api_key=57ee3318536b23ee81d6b27e36997cde&format=json&_=1520772613660", function(error, response, body) {
                var data = JSON.parse(body);
                //console.log(data)
                var songs = data.toptracks.track;
                songs.forEach(function (song) {
                    console.log(song.name)
                })
            });
        }
    });
}
```